# Returning both right and error causing results

Tags: python

I have a small python function that goes through N files and for each returns some value which are then return as a list when all files are processed.

Most of them will process correctly, but some will fail. I need to relay that information to the caller of the function.

Only thing I can think of right now is to return two lists - one with the processed results and the other with files that failed, but it just feels wrong to do it that way.

Note that the function is a static utility function, so I can't really store the error list in a member variable.

Comment: 2 lists seems appropriate to me, not to mention legible... or appending a key of some sort to the beginning/end of the results that failed (i.e \*FAIL\*) if you want just one list.

Comment: Why don't you return a dict with key as the file names and value as the result from processing of the filenames.

Comment: I think the approach you just mentioned is fine if you're purely making a static function. Nothing wrong with returning 2 lists if they serve a purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map the results to a dict in format such as this:

```
{ file0: “pass”, file1: “pass”, file2: “fail” }
```

Then you can query both the key and values, the values of “pass” and “fail” designate whether the file processing was a success or not. file0, file1 etc are the returned files after processing